# Embed google map in idesign

Tags: offline, adobe-indesign

I design custom travel guides. I am going crazy trying to find a way to insert offline zoomable maps in them. I use indesign CC. So far all I have managed is to embed google maps in the document and export it as an interactive pdf, but it needs internet connection to load the map.

Is there any way to insert offline maps in the document? I would be willing to switch to another software or export format if needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know about designs but If you want offline maps then you should use [TileMill](https://www.mapbox.com/tilemill/).Also if you want to explore other options, see [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/23720/simple-way-to-have-an-offline-web-based-map). Not sure if this will be helpful to you but if you get someone to extract the PNGs for you, I suppose you could make it work.